# SonarQube server [http://localhost:9000] can not be reached :Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to download libraries from server:

Tags: docker, sonarqube

Sonarqube dev edition  is running in container its accessible through public ip:9000(aws ec2 ubuntu).github apps configuration is valid, added sonar token and sonar host url values as given by sonarqube integration with github actions workflow , No idea why its pointing to localhost[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eaw8r.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Error:  SonarQube server [http://localhost:9000] can not be reached
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  17.407 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-08-03T10:27:25Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error:  Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project OCRTextractAssembly: Unable

Answer (score 0):

issue got resolved when i run my Sonarqube with https and open to public access